# regular expression allow only one specific special character and numbers in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

i want to get interest value from users through asp.net textbox. it accepts numbers and optional to enter "%" only. prohibit to enter any other special characters or any alphabet letters.

```
                      <div class="row">
                       <div class="medium-6 columns">
                      Current Interest (APR) that you pay
                      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgv2" 
                               ControlToValidate="txtCurrentInterest" runat="server" 
                               ErrorMessage="Interest be in numbers" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" 
                               ValidationExpression="">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rv6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCurrentInterest" ErrorMessage="Current Interest is Required" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrentInterest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                       </div>                    
                    </div>
```

Comment: I guess this: `^\d+%?$`

Comment: thank you for the support but this isn't work

Comment: Then, please, show all possible inputs to validate.

Comment: need to accept 13.52%  or 13.52 or 1.25

Comment: Now this is clearer: `^\d+(\.\d+)?%?$`

Comment: I'll make it an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^\d+(\.\d+)?%?$`

- `^` and `$` Denote start and end of the string (i.e. string must fully match)
- `\d+` One or several digits
- `(\.\d+)?` Zero or one decimal part of the number
- `%?` Zero or one percent sign

Answer (score 0):

These expressions might work:

```
ValidationExpression="\d+%?" // Johny's advice in the comment 
ValidationExpression="[0-9]+%?" // one digit or more
ValidationExpression="[0-9][0-9]*%?"
ValidationExpression="[0-9][0-9]*%?"
ValidationExpression="[0-9]{1,7}%?" // one to 7 digits for instance
```

If start and end anchors are allowed, you can include those, such as:

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{1,7}%?$" // one to 7 digits for instance
```

[Please see additional info in this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_validators.htm).